# Move selected objects from one place to another and back again to original position javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a keyword selector in where a user selects one or more keywords from one box. Those keywords that are selected are then taken out of the original box and put into the one alongside it, displaying the selected keyword.

I wish to store the keyword elements in an array but i am having trouble figuring out how the user would actually click on the element and display it in the opposite box. The only way I seem to be making any progress is with onclick() functions etc... for the individual elements but thats not what I am looking for.

Is it possible to move these elements from within their contained div to the the empty box div ??. Any advise or responses on this would be appreciated, attached is a code snippet to get a better grasp on the problem. Thanks everyone.

```js
var kwords = [
  "audi",
  "bmw",
  "chevrolet",
  "honda",
  "mercedes",
]

function car1() {
  document.getElementById("inner").style.color = 'blue';
}
```

```css
#boxleft {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
}

#boxright {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}

#inner {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="boxleft">
  <div id="inner" onclick="car1();">audi</div>
  <div id="inner1">bmw</div>
  <div id="inner2">chevrolet</div>
  <div id="inner3">honda</div>
  <div id="inner4">mercedes</div>
</div>
<div id="boxright"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach `click` listener to many elements at once. Take a look at [this codepen](https://codepen.io/selenir/pen/VrvxBE).

What is happening here:

1. `document.querySelectorAll('.keyword')` looks for all elements with `keyword` class in the document (take a look how I've changed the HTML section)
2. Inside `forEach` loop, line `element.addEventListener('click', toggleKeyword)` adds  `click` listener to every found element (which is equivalent to manually assigning `onClick` attribute)
3. Now when you click on a keyword, `toggleKeyword` function is executed:
4. `var element = event.target;` is the element you clicked
5. `boxLeft` and `boxRight` variables are these two divs with `boxLeft` and `boxRight` ids
6. `var newParent = element.parentNode.id === 'boxleft' ? boxRight : boxLeft;` this line checks which the new parent element should be, if you clicked on `div` inside the `leftbox` it should go to the `rightbox` and vice versa.
7. Finally we remove element from it's current parent and add to the opposite one.